# Cover the body using a background image with a fixed border

Tags: html, css, background, margin

I got a little project but it brings me so much trouble...

How to make the image and the white border cover the viewport, where the border is equal all the time?

Here is a screendump of the layout I want, created with Photoshop.

[image]

The CSS I tried so far.

```css
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(../img/bg_border.jpg);
}
```

If you have a clue, any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: do you have the html as well? seeing that would be a good help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but you could make the background smaller, for example `background-size:calc( 100vw - 50px) calc(100vh - 50px);` where `50px` 2x is the desired thickness of your border: http://jsfiddle.net/4yLwprrx/

Comment: adaptative border ? vh or vw units can be an hint, transparent border and background-clip too . example: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XmaLRg but what is your meaning of "adaptative borders ?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1000-600-1.jpg);
    border: 50px solid white;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello you need to wrap your content into `.wrapper`and the background image on `cover` inside it.

with your height : http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/RWZzGq

and with fluid fullscreen height : http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/jbLjVb

There is a lot of ways of doing that - that's just two of them

**EDIT** my mistake - community was right

So as redemption I'm giving code here in snippet.
We learn every day as do I.

**First solution:** with your height of wrapper container

```css
body{
  padding: 40px;
}
.wrapper{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

**Second solution:** fluid height of wrapper container

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper{
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left:40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  background-image: url("http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: @isherwood what? you dont know codepen? new here ?:D

Comment: lol why did I get downvote? well...what and ignorance. What is point of helping when you get downvote.. that community is going down.

Comment: So well you must know jsfiddle and codepen to give live example of solution - where you can give it faster than here...

Comment: and there is important link when you hove you can get it , and it is reaachable and online. so nope.

Comment: @LGSon well looks like everyone get downvoted for no reason. I dont see point of helping anyone here anymore if get downvote for giving two viable solutions.

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński And whats ment by having code on this site is as long as this site have the question, answer with code it will always be available for users, but if, for any reason, codepen or fiddle etc. close down or clean up old code, it might get lost.

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński I don't think you got downvoted for your answer, I think it was for your comments

Comment: I didnt wrote any comment before i get downvote. So anyway if someone dont like my attitude then report comment not anwser which some1 can use later. Learn to use from community please

Comment: @LGSon I did rewrite my anwser as you were right so hopefully you'll un-downvote my anwser. Thank you, and also my behaviour wasn't the best one.

Comment: @isherwood As above I wrote comment to LGSon I did rewrite my anwser so hopefully it will be right now properly writen anwser. Thank you

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński I never gave you a down vote, I gave you an up vote.